# MySQL - how to store results of GROUP BY for use in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

How do I fix the following query? My attempt to alias the result of the SELECT query into table `tmp` does not work.

```
INSERT INTO vote_counts (list_id, node_id, num_down_votes) 
  (SELECT vl.list_id, vl.node_id, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM vote_logs vl 
   WHERE vl.node_id=2442703 AND vl.agree_type='DOWN_VOTE' 
GROUP BY vl.list_id) tmp
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_down_votes = tmp.c;
```

The `vote_counts` table has a unique key constraint on `(list_id, node_id)`.

Comment: You don't need the alias -- that's not a derived table/inline view.

Comment: Is this what you meant?
INSERT INTO vote_counts (list_id, node_id, num_down_votes) 
  (SELECT vl.list_id, vl.node_id, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM vote_logs vl 
   WHERE vl.node_id=2442703 AND vl.agree_type='DOWN_VOTE' 
GROUP BY vl.list_id) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_down_votes = c;
That doesn't work. It says unknown column 'c' in 'field list'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO vote_counts (list_id, node_id, num_down_votes) 
SELECT vl.list_id, vl.node_id, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM vote_logs vl 
WHERE vl.node_id=2442703 AND vl.agree_type='DOWN_VOTE' 
GROUP BY vl.list_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_down_votes = vl.c;
```

If `vl.c` doesn't work, you may need to use `Count(vl.*)` since it's an alias -- not sure, would have to test it.

--EDIT

Perhaps using a `subquery` will resolve this issue:

```
INSERT INTO vote_counts (list_id, node_id, num_down_votes) 
SELECT list_id, node_id, c
FROM (
    SELECT vl.list_id, vl.node_id, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM vote_logs vl 
    WHERE vl.node_id=2442703 AND vl.agree_type='DOWN_VOTE' 
    GROUP BY vl.list_id
) tempTable
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_down_votes = tempTable.c;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Maybe try using a subquery?  See edits and let me know.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, the subquery resolved my issues with the combination of GROUPY BY and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Thanks!