# mysql - on duplicate key update, joined table field

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, insert-update

kb_nid is unique key and c_nodes table; include kb_nid, runState, startedTime fields

I want before table update, compare old table but get this error:

> "SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'cn.runState' in 'field list'"

```
INSERT INTO c_nodes(kb_nid,runState,startedTime)
    SELECT n.id, n.nState>10 as runState, NULL as startedTime 
    FROM node n 
    LEFT JOIN  c_nodes cn ON n.id =cn.kb_nid
    GROUP BY n.id
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE startedTime=IF(cn.runState<>VALUES(runState) ,NOW(),cn.startedTime)
```

I can't see any problem.

Edit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8a84

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you want someone to help you, you'd better provided schema of all tables involved.

Comment: As a guess, try to remove "cn" aliases from `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` block

Comment: thanks @Jacobian if I have remove cn, I can't compare old state;
Meanwhile edit for sqlfiddle my post, please  check again .

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with subquery. I guess the error reason is **GROUP BY**

```
INSERT INTO c_nodes(kb_nid,runState,startedTime) 
SELECT n.id,runState,startedTime  FROM (
SELECT n.id, n.nState>10 as runState, NULL as startedTime 
FROM node n 
GROUP BY n.id) tt
LEFT JOIN  c_nodes cn ON tt.id =cn.kb_nid
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE startedTime=IF(cn.runState<>VALUES(runState) ,NOW(),cn.startedTime)
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533265/3952108